# How to write this for loop in a single line in Python?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How do I write the following as one line in Python?

```
my_list = ['ab1c', 'fo2o', 'ba3r']
for i in xrange(len(my_list)):
    my_list[i] = my_list[i][1:3]
```

I tried

```
my_list = [x for i in xrange(len(my_list)) my_list[i] = my_list[i][2:3]]
```

But it only returns an invalid syntax error

Comment: Note that this would be neater with `for i, s in enumerate(my_list): my_list[i] = s[1:3]`; iterating over `range(len(...))` is generally considered unpythonic.

Comment: You can use like my_list = [i[1:3] for i in my_list]  
(or)  

my_list = map(lambda x: x[1:3],my_list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List comprehension method -

```
my_list[:] = [x[1:3] for x in my_list]
```

`[:]` is used so that `my_list` is mutated in place, just as your `for` loop method does.

Demo -

```
>>> my_list = ['ab1c', 'fo2o', 'ba3r']
>>> my_list[:] = [x[1:3] for x in my_list]
>>> my_list
['b1', 'o2', 'a3']
```

---

As asked in comments -

> Can you elaborate on the difference with `my_list = [x[1:3] for x in my_list]`

A very simple code example to show the difference -

```
>>> my_list = ['ab1c', 'fo2o', 'ba3r']
>>> a = my_list
>>> my_list = [x[1:3] for x in my_list]
>>> my_list
['b1', 'o2', 'a3']
>>> a
['ab1c', 'fo2o', 'ba3r']
```

The above method results in -

```
>>> my_list = ['ab1c', 'fo2o', 'ba3r']
>>> a = my_list
>>> my_list[:] = [x[1:3] for x in my_list]
>>> my_list
['b1', 'o2', 'a3']
>>> a
['b1', 'o2', 'a3']
```

This is because list comprehensions create a new list, when you use `my_list[:]` on the left side of the assignment operator you are asking Python to mutate `my_list` in place (but when you do `my_list = <something>` , you are just making `my_list` reference a new list, instead of mutating the original list).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference with `my_list = [x[1:3] for x in my_list]` ?

Comment: @wap26 that creates a new list, rather than replacing the old one

Comment: Maybe keeping the same list was not a requirement although the original code did.

Comment: @wap26 ...yes, maybe. And if there are no other references to `my_list` it doesn't really matter. It's not clear what point you're trying to make.

Comment: @wap26 correct, I just used that to be exactly equivalent to what the `for` loop did.